# radio input is not submitting, only the fist radio value

Tags: php, jquery

I struggle to submit all my radio buttons with different values but with the same "names", how can I do that from jquery?

If I submit it saves only the first value not that I have checked. Some help here please!

If I check value Duo in the db I have value Solo , if I check value Grupuri , the same in the db with value Solo, I don't know where am I wrong here..some assistance needed...

I'm new with this.

HTML code with radio input:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="sectiune">
  <h4 class="info-text">Va rugam sa alegeti sectiunea pentru momentul dvs.</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset" >
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Solo">
          <input type="radio" id="sectiuni" name="sectiuni" value="Solo">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="assets/img/icons/solo.svg"/>
          </div>
          <h6>Solo</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
          <input type="radio" id="sectiuni" name="sectiuni" value="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
          <div class="icon">
            <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/duotrio.svg"/>
          </div>
          <h6>Duo/Trio/Quartet</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Grupuri 5-12 dansatori">
          <input type="radio" id="sectiuni" name="sectiuni" value="Grupuri">
          <div class="icon">
            <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/grupuri.png"/>
          </div>
          <h6>Grupuri</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Formaţii peste 13 dansatori.">
          <input type="radio" id="sectiuni" name="sectiuni" value="Formatii">
          <div class="icon">
            <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/formatii.png"/>
          </div>
          <h6>Formatii</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$( "#inscriere" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $( this ),
  disciplina = $form.find( "[type='radio'][name=disciplina]" ).val(),
  sectiuni = $form.find( "[type='radio'][name=sectiuni]" ).val(),

  url = 'insert.php?disciplina='+disciplina;
  var posting = $.post( url, {
    disciplina: disciplina,
    sectiuni: sectiuni
  });
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert("done");
  });
});
```

And my PHP insert:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", ""); 
if(isset($_GET['disciplina'])!="") {
  $disciplina =  $_POST['disciplina'];
  $sectiuni = $_POST['sectiuni'];

  $save=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO momente SET
    disciplina='$disciplina', 
    sectiuni='$sectiuni');
  if ($save == true) {
    echo "done";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: to create a radio group from some radio inputs, you should use the same `name`, but different `id`'s, or you can also omit the `id`s if you don't need it - https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio. Generally speaking, avoid to use twice the same `id`...

Comment: Good, i will change the id names, and what's next? the thing is i use boostrap wizard form , instead of default radio's i have images

Comment: You don't want radio *values*. Those radios will *always* have values. You want the value of *the one radio that is checked*. So you need to add `:checked` to the selector. This is one case in which INPUT behavior differs between different types of input field.

Comment: I just have done that..nothing..

Comment: I have managed to have'it work, i changed the radio into checkbox and class wizard-radio to wizard-checkbox , and i have added :checked to the selectors, and worked. Thank's for the advices!